# Exchange WebService sends only plain Text through c#

Tags: c#, web-services, exchangewebservices

I have a program that sends eMail through the Exchange Webservice:

```
//EXCHANGE API
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

//BODY
string mBody = "<strong>TEXT</strong> Test";

//SETUP
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
service.Url = new Uri("https://"+uriVar);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userNameVar, passwordVar);
EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
message.Subject = mSubject;
message.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML,mBody);
message.ToRecipients.Add(recipient);
message.Save();

//Adding Image(s)
string fileFacebook = "facebook.png";
message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment("facebook.png", fileFacebook);
message.Attachments[0].IsInline = true;
message.Attachments[0].ContentId = "imgFacebook";

//Send
message.Send();
```

(the image is added in the original body, not in this example)

However, the eMail goes through as plain text, I cannot find out why. I am pretty sure it worked some time ago, is it possible that something has been changed on the Server? If so, what could it be?

Comment: Are you sending the Message Internally or Externally ? if its external you might want to look to see if a remote domain has been setup for that address http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996309(v=exchg.150).aspx#BKMK_MessageFormat it maybe you have a remote domain that set to convert the messages to plain text. You can also configure conversion tracing http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397226(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Great, the first link looks like what I am looking for, though I have to contact our admin to change that. The second one I don't understand but will get back to that if the first solution fails.